# link a div in another page in url with an anchor tag Django

Tags: django, url, anchor

I am trying to access a div in another page using an anchor tag and url in Django.

Here is a html,

```
<a href="{% url 'anotherpage#show' %}>click here </a>
```

In another page,

```
<div id="show">link to this div </div>
```

How would I access the `show` div with an url?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to link to the page first. then link to the `Anchor`

```
## assume this will take you to the main page. 
<a href="{% url 'anotherpage' %}>Page URL</a>
```

Then all you have to do is to add the required anchor after the url tag.

```
<a href="{% url 'anotherpage' %}#show">Page URL to show directly. </a>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Bro you're a damn champ, I of course tried to come up with a convoluted way to use parameters to achieve this. I did not not know the template language was this thorough